# How to make thinkfan not cause jerky fan behavior?

Tags: fan, fancontrol

I have thinkfan installed and it runs fine. However, I've noticed that it frequently changes fan rpms and this causes the fan to act rather jerky. For example, it will increase in speed (and sound), and then drop back down to a lower speed (and softer sound) frequently.

When I use windows, the fan usually operates at a more constant speed, and changes rpms gradually, rather than "jerking". With ubuntu, sometimes it feels like my fan is like a quiet racecar changing gears when it changes rpms.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Here is my /etc/thinkfan.conf file:

```
# lots of comments
tp_fan /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
tp_thermal /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal

(0, 0, 43)
(1, 42, 50)
(2, 49, 55)
(3, 54, 60)
(4, 59, 63)
(5, 62, 68)
(6, 68, 75)
(7, 70, 86)
(127, 85, 32767)
```

Comment: Lets start with the missing info. What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: what do the actual temps look like before and after it ramps up